# MySQL "Warning: Data truncated for column" appears only for some rows even though they are the same length as other?

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I am creating queries in Python 2.7 and I am using MySQLdb library to execute these queries. I am trying to insert data from one table to another and only for few rows (always the same rows, I did multiple runs) ige this warning "Warning: Data truncated for column" on a certain column.

- OLD column is defined as some_column `VARCHAR(255)`
- NEW column is defined as some_other_column `VARCHAR(8)`

Never mind the obvious difference in  their sizes, the data I am trying to insert is always 8 characters long. And data that is truncated (lost) is always just the last character.

I've tried to set column to `VARCHAR(9)` and now it's working but that is not a desired result, tables shouldn't be altered for a problem that isn't there...

Sample data I am trying to insert but it gets truncated:

```
MOW15017
```

Sample data I am inserting that works:

```
LON15023
```

(sample data is copied directly from table after insert into column altered to `VARCHAR(9)`)

Is there anything I am missing here?

Is it encoding issue?

Additional note: executing query directly in database works without any warning, using Python MySQLdb I get warnings on 8 rows (cca 1000 rows in total)

Comment: Same problem for SQL Server too? (As it's tagged...)

Comment: Nope, sorry, mistagged... Suggestions made me do it...

Comment: varchar(8) should give you 8 bytes of usable storage - i.e. your should be able to store 8 characters in this field.  Do the values get truncated if you execute the insert statements using the MySQL CLI interface, as opposed to executing the queries from your python program?

Comment: Does select * from oldtable where some_column <> substr(some_column,1,8) give any returned rows?

Comment: @mti2935 values get truncated only when query is executed trough python...
jarlh: using substring skips warning but it still truncates the value...

Comment: @jarlh: using substring skips warning but it still truncates the value... BUT using substring(column, 2, 9) gives correct value for those 8 that get truncated. all others loose first character though...

Comment: So there are some values of length 9 then. Don't you have substr(some_column,1,8) in your INSERT statement?

Comment: No, I am not using it. I tried now and found a "solution" with CASE statement... You can probably guess...

Comment: `SELECT LENGTH(col), CHAR_LENGTH(col), HEX(col) FROM tbl WHERE ...` -- I think that will discover the problem.  (Use the WHERE clause to pick the truncated value.)

Answer (score 0):

After some fiddling around with a bit of help from comments on my question I found something that works for me but imo shouldn't really be practiced...

New query: (in old one, instead of CASE was just giraffe AS giraffe)

```
INSERT INTO table (column1, ...)
    SELECT CASE 
               WHEN LENGTH(giraffe) > 8
               THEN SUBSTRING(giraffe, 2, 9)
               ELSE giraffe
           END AS column1,
           ...
    FROM table2
```

I don't like since if there are cases where I can have invisible magical first character, who's guaranteeing me that there won't be 2 magical invisible character...